# I need XmlDocument to save special characters as code instead of symbol

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm working with a third party who insists that they need xml special characters as their codes ie: `&amp;`&#174 instead of the (R) symbol. Every time I save an XmlDocument though I get the symbol. I can't seem to make it output the codes.

I need

```
<tag>Words...&amp;&#174;</tag>
```

instead of

```
<tag>Words...®</tag>
```

Comment: Can you use the string literal '@'?

Comment: Please show a small example, and show how you would like it to appear. Also, tell us how  you know that you "get the symbol". Did you check on disk?

Comment: Your example does not match, did you mean `<tag>Words...&®</tag>` for the source string?

Comment: Please be very precise about the desired outcome here. `&amp;&#174` makes no sense. `&amp;#174;` does but it is double encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by creating a custom XmlWriter, For example

```
public class CustomXmlWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public CustomXmlWriter(TextWriter wr)
        : base(wr)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
        text = String.Join("",text.Select(Encode));
        base.WriteRaw(text);
    }

    string Encode(char c)
    {
        if (c < 127) return c.ToString();
        return "&#" + ((int)c).ToString() + ";";
    }
}
```

I tested above function with

```
XElement xElem = new XElement("tag", "Words...®");
StringWriter wr = new StringWriter();
xElem.Save(new CustomXmlWriter(wr));
var xml = wr.ToString();
```

and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it as CDATA:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var root = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Root"));
root.AppendChild(doc.CreateCDataSection("&&#174"));
```

This document will have the following text form, and the CDATA section prevents the XML processor from trying to interpret special characters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Root><![CDATA[&&#174]]></Root>
```

Comment: I don't think they're going to like that <![CDATA> tag. I need just the code